Python from Java does not start
I make a calculator in which we enter an expression and it shows us the result. I work on the phone and use Replit for work. The problem is that it shows us not the result, but null.
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter expression: ");
        String expression = scan.nextLine();

        try {
            File file = new File("expression.txt");

            if(!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
            pw.print(expression);
            pw.close();

            String pythonFile = "calculate.py";
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod -R 777 python " + pythonFile);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println(br.readLine());
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

Also my python code.


expressionFile = open('expression.txt', 'a+'))

expression = str(expressionFile.read())

result = eval(expression)

expressionFile.wtite("=" + str(result))

print(expressionFile.read())

expressionFile.close()

I tried using ProcessBuilder and change the path calculate.py, but it didn't help.
Changed: I cleaned chmod -R 777 and now getting this error
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.Process Builder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1143)
    at java.base/java.lang.Process Builder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:594)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:418) 
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:315)
    at Main.main (Main.java:28)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error 2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:314)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:244)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110)
    ... 5 more

Changed 2: I work on Android. I tried replacing chmod with dir, ls and echo, but they all output calculate.py, and echo output python calculate.py.
Changed 3: Help is no longer needed. I found what was wrong. I opened the `expression.txt' file to add text, but it should have been opened for reading. Now my python file looks like this:
expressionFile = open("expression.txt", "r+")
expression = expressionFile.read()
result = eval(expression)
print(f"{expression}={result}")
expressionFile.close()


Does the same command work from the command line?

How does the command chmod -R 777 python calculate.py make any sense?

I tried to write "python calculate.py", but it throws an error that no such file or directory.

@Ilarion chmod does not start anything, it makes no sense that you use it. You have to use something like python calculate.py. Please [edit] your question to include the full complete error message and/or stacktrace you get.

@Ilarion Then python might not be installed or is not in the PATH variable of your system. Depending on the system you are using (which we don't know btw.), try other commands like dir, ls, echo to see if the execution of a program works in general (and the you get the first line of the output of that program). Then [edit] your question with the findings you have.
